# Separating Routes to different files brings errors

Tags: php, laravel

I am trying to organise my routes by putting them in different sub folders, but in doing so has made my application have quite a few errors. I think it has to do with the way I've done my route service provider?

I am also not entirely sure what the api does
api.php:

```
 Route::middleware('auth:sanctum')->get('/user', function (Request $request) {
     return $request->user();
 });
```

RouteServiceProvider:

```
<?php
 
namespace App\Providers;
 
use Illuminate\Cache\RateLimiting\Limit;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Support\Providers\RouteServiceProvider as ServiceProvider;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\RateLimiter;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;
 
class RouteServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    /**
     * The path to the "home" route for your application.
     *
     * This is used by Laravel authentication to redirect users after login.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    public const HOME = '/admin'; // (I realised after logging in it would redirect me to                              //whatever this was so I changed it to admin as home just replied 404)
 
    /**
     * If specified, this namespace is automatically applied to your controller routes.
     *
     * In addition, it is set as the URL generator's root namespace.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $namespace = null;
 
    /**
     * Define your route model bindings, pattern filters, etc.
     *
     * @return void
     */
 
    public function boot()
    {
        $this->configureRateLimiting();
 
        $this->routes(function () {
           
            Route::prefix('api')
                ->middleware('api')
                ->namespace($this->namespace)
                ->group(base_path('routes/api/api.php'));

            Route::prefix('admin')
                ->middleware(['web','auth'])
                ->namespace($this->namespace)
                ->group(base_path('routes/web/posts.php'));

            Route::prefix('admin')
                ->middleware(['web','auth'])
                ->namespace($this->namespace)
                ->group(base_path('routes/web/users.php'));

            Route::middleware('web')
                ->namespace($this->namespace)
                ->group(base_path('routes/web/web.php'));
        });
    }
 
    /**
     * Configure the rate limiters for the application.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    protected function configureRateLimiting()
    {
        RateLimiter::for('api', function (Request $request) {
            return Limit::perMinute(60);
        });
    }
}
```

My posts give me the most errors as my create a post and view all posts tab returns 404 not found. Also my users routes aren't 100% a tab named 'create a user' is now 'create a post' and now takes me to view users instead of create a user

posts.php(route):

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Foundation\Application;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;
use Inertia\Inertia;
use App\Http\Controllers\UserController;

    Route::get('posts/{post}', [App\Http\Controllers\PostController::class, 'show'])->name('post');
    Route::get('posts/index', [App\Http\Controllers\PostController::class, 'index'])->name('post.index');
    Route::post('posts', [App\Http\Controllers\PostController::class, 'store'])->name('post.store');
    Route::get('posts/create', [App\Http\Controllers\PostController::class, 'create'])->name('post.create');
    Route::patch('posts/{post}/update', [App\Http\Controllers\PostController::class, 'update'])->name('post.update');
    Route::delete('posts/{post}/destroy', [App\Http\Controllers\PostController::class, 'destroy'])->name('post.destroy');
    Route::get('posts/{post}/edit', [App\Http\Controllers\PostController::class, 'edit'])->middleware('can:view,post')->name('post.edit');
```

Answer (score 0):

These are in the wrong order:

```
 Route::get('posts/{post}', [App\Http\Controllers\PostController::class, 'show'])->name('post');
 Route::get('posts/index', [App\Http\Controllers\PostController::class, 'index'])->name('post.index');
 Route::get('posts/create', [App\Http\Controllers\PostController::class, 'create'])->name('post.create');
```

`/posts/index` can't be reached as the previous route matches this URI and thus will always take precedence (likely post with id of "index" doesn't exist)

Same problem with create.

Just put the catch-all route at the bottom to solve your problem.

**Alternate solution:**

You could also use laravel route `resources` ([docs](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/controllers#resource-controllers)) and make that whole file one line (maybe with a couple of tweaks in how you call them):

`Route::resource('posts', PostController::class)`

or with `->only(...)` if you only need a couple of routes

`Route::resource('posts', PostController::class)->only(['index', 'show'])`